# feedparser module is not importing from spyder IDE

Tags: pip, package, python-3.6, spyder, feedparser

i was trying to work with pydelicious APi,i tried to install it from cmd using this command:

```
pip install pydelicious
```

but was unsuccessful as cmd said:

```
C:\Users\MOBASSIR>pip install pydelicious
Collecting pydelicious
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/42/0ef959fa6b686862b02ae343e58ce7764bbf8e7c37de1eeaa7e6418fd8d9/pydelicious-0.6.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MOBASSIR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2xpulis3\pydelicious\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        import pydelicious
      File "C:\Users\MOBASSIR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2xpulis3\pydelicious\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 171
        raise DeliciousItemExistsError, params['url']
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MOBASSIR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2xpulis3\pydelicious\ "
```

then i  downloaded the pydelicious module from here : https://gist.github.com/takashi/2967f9c5ec8ebab5f622 i placed that pydelicious.py file in the same folder where i am writing python codes.then i tried to import pydelicious and i got error that no module named 'feedparser'..then again i installed feedparser using this command in cmd : "pip install feedparser"..after sometimes i got reply from cmd that installation successful.then i again tried to import pydelicious from a python file and now i'm getting this error : "

```
runfile('C:/Users/MOBASSIR/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/MOBASSIR/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-73d3194ff832>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/MOBASSIR/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/MOBASSIR/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\MOBASSIR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\MOBASSIR\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/MOBASSIR/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pydelicious

  File "C:\Users\MOBASSIR\.spyder-py3\pydelicious.py", line 100, in <module>
    import feedparser

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feedparser'  "
```

now if i type pip install feedparser in cmd i get this message : "Requirement already satisfied: feedparser in c:\users\mobassir\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (5.2.1)"

how can i solve this problem and use pydelicious api? i am using python 3.6 and the pydelicious module that i've downloaded is of version 3.

Comment: Why do you need it? `pydelicious` is an outdated Python API for a social bookmark platform that is not available since 2009. It works only with Python 2, the last version was [0.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/pydelicious/), where from have you downloaded version 3?

Comment: i was trying to work with link recommendation system through a book called programming collective intelligence by toby segaran,there the writer worked with pydelicious to make a link recommendation system,but i am unable to work with pydelicious..if it is not available in python 3 then please see the link : https://gist.github.com/takashi/2967f9c5ec8ebab5f622 and tell me how did he used that pydelicious module  in python 3? but when i tried to import this same module i get errors,i can't use that module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code at the gist is **the** pydelicious update for Python 3. To install it first remove old pydelicious:

```
pip uninstall pydelicious
```

And then copy pydelicious from [raw github link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/takashi/2967f9c5ec8ebab5f622/raw/a15baa8364f3795a1b21866696db95c20c1c3ac1/pydelicious.py).

But it will not work anyway — the API URL was shut many years ago.